# What is the moment generating function of $P(X=x)=\alpha\theta^x$?

Tags: self-study, moments

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable such that $P(X=x)=\alpha\theta^x$, $x=1,2,\ldots,$ and $0 < \theta < 1$ and $P(X=0)=1-\sum^\infty_{x=1}\alpha\theta^x$, where $\alpha$ is a constant. Find the $M_X(t)$ with its appropriate ranges for $t$ and $\alpha$.

My work so far:

$M_X(t)=E(e^{tx})=\sum^\infty_{x=1}\alpha e^{tx}\theta^x= \alpha \sum^\infty_{x=1} e^{tx} \theta^x = \alpha b\theta(1+b\theta^2+b\theta^3+\cdots)$, where $b=e^t$. I just do not know how to manipulate this series so that we get a nice function for $M_X(t)$. Also, I am wondering how you can make use of $P(X=0)$ in the solution.

Thank you.

Comment: You have made a couple of mistakes already.  You have dropped the term $x=0$ and you have not expanded the terms out correctly (they should have the same powers on $b$ and $\theta$).  Once you correct that, you should be able to find the solution using the rules for infinite geometric sums.

Comment: I see that I forgot the $x=0$ term. I factored out a $b$ from my previous expansion- is this an incorrect move? My answer after using the $x=0$ term is $M_X(t)=e^xt$, which does not seem right.

Comment: See if this works. In your question, your have  $\alpha\Sigma^\infty_{x=1} e^{tx}\theta^x.$ The sum is a geometric series, which you can sum. Then add $P(X=0)$ term (maybe simpler if you sum the series). // When you get it, maybe post your own answer, which I'd upvote. // Maybe change question title to include "0-Inflated Geometric"

Comment: Will do. I will post it tomorrow afternoon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See @Glen-b's comment.

What follows finds the MGF for an *ordinary* geometric distribution (where $\alpha = 1-\theta)$ that
counts the number of failures before the first success, and so
has support on the nonnegative integers. [There are other versions
of the geometric distribution.]

To make typing easier, I will let $p$ be the success probability and
$q = 1-p.$ Thus $P(X = k) = pq^k,$ for $k = 0, 1, \dots.$ Then
the MGF $M_X(t)$ is found as follows:

$$M_X(t) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{tk}pq^k = 
p\sum_0 (qe^t)^k = \frac{p}{1-qe^t},$$
where we have summed an infinite series at the last equality,
subject to the restriction that $qe^t < 1.$ [You should express
this in terms of $t$ when stating the values of $t$ for which
the MGF exists.]

Knowing the form of $P(X=0)$ makes it easy to include the $0$th
term into the series from the start.

*Ref:* You may want to look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) where both of
the most commonly used versions of the geometric distribution are
shown (we're using their second version). Also useful may be 
[this page](https://www.math.arizona.edu/~tgk/464_10/chap4_9_29.pdf),
for its clear exposition, even though it uses the alternate version of
the PDF. Finally, [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3353290/confused-about-the-mean-of-negative-binomial-distribution/3353515#3353515) from a sister site finds the mean of a geometric distribution without using the MGF.

*Addendum:* You roll a fair die until the first `6` occurs. The number $X$ of failures before that success, it our geometric random variable. Find $E(X).$ First, $M_X^\prime(t) = pqe^t/(1-qe^t)^2.$
Then $M_X^\prime(0) = q/p = \frac{5/6}{1/6} = 5.$

This is the version of the geometric distribution implemented in R.

```
x = 0:500;  p = 1/6;  q = 5/6  
pdf=p*q^x;  sum(x*pdf)
[1] 5             # summing 500 terms suffices for E(X)
sum(x*dgeom(x,p))
[1] 5             # same thing, using R's function 'dgeom'
set.seed(916);  mean(rgeom(10^6, 1/6))
[1] 4.99737       # avg of 10^6 simulated 'games' for 2-place accuracy
```

Comment: I can follow all of your math. However, can you please share how you identified this distribution as geometric. I believe that if I was able to identify that it was a geometric distribution, I would have been able to solve this problem relatively quick. Love the R example, too. Thank you.

Comment: The actual distribution identified in the question is a zero-inflated\* geometric, not a geometric $\:\:$\*(or more strictly, a zero-modified geometric, since it might be deflated relative to a geometric)

Comment: @Glen_b. Thanks for correction. Looking at it again.

Comment: @Edison: Answer is OK for geometric, but I misunderstood the expression for $P(X=0).$ Sorry, it really is a bit messier. See Glen-b's comment. // When the first term is inflated, all other terms must be deflated accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. So, how would this change the answer? Everything seems correct in your latest edits, but I am curious as to how a zero-modified geometric distribution would change both the answer and the nature of this problem.

Comment: I noticed that the answer has been edited. So does the fact that this distribution is a zero-modified distribution change the problem, or was this just something to note?

Comment: Yes 0-inflated geom is more general. // Intent was to edit the question to recognize I worked a special case of the intended problem.